# Get Recently Liked Photos of a user by Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get the recent photos (duration:1 week) liked by an user by facebook graph api.I searched about it a lot but can't find any suitable resource.

In the facebook graph api documentation,i find the following link:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=...

But this only shows the pages I liked.How can I solve the problem?
Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API that returns the information you're looking for - to see if a user likes a particular photo you'll have to check the photo itself via the API and see if the user likes it.